# Failed to build econml shap

Tags: installation, pip

I am trying to install `econml` via `pip install econml`.

However I get the following error message:

> ERROR: Failed building wheel for shap   Running setup.py clean for
> shap Failed to build econml shap ERROR: Could not build wheels for
> econml, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Does anyone know what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly Make sure You have installed required `Python` version !

[image]

---

Than if you have **still** issue **Try** to use this `command` to resolve this issue:

```
pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
```

**OR** second option:

```
pip install setuptools --upgrade
```

If you have any doubts check the [project description](https://pypi.org/project/econml/), [github docs](https://github.com/microsoft/EconML) or official [docs](https://econml.azurewebsites.net/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately I get the same error after i tried running one of the suggestions. I do also get this error: Installing collected packages: PyQtWebEngine-Qt5, PyQtWebEngine
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
spyder 5.1.5 requires pyqt5<5.13, but you have pyqt5 5.15.6 which is incompatible.
spyder 5.1.5 requires pyqtwebengine<5.13, but you have pyqtwebengine 5.15.5 which is incompatible. Is it possible this is the problem?

Comment: @Ang What are OS, Python and Pip version You using ?

Comment: OS 19042.1348,  Python 3.9.7 and pip 21.3.1. Does that help?

Comment: @Ang Try to install newest version of wheel package https://pypi.org/project/wheel/ and restart terminal, and try again..

Comment: @Ang If You want to install and use econml package, You have to install Python 3.8  first!  This package will not work with python 3.9.7 :-)!

Comment: @Ang I have just successfully install econml on 3.8.10 Python so issue is solved ;-)! Good Luck ! I hope You will be content!

Comment: I installed Microsoft visual C++ and this solved the issue for me. Thanks for your help!